# SQL Server Linked server query problem (group by)

Tags: sql-server, oracle, linked-server, odbc

I have been using an old SQL Server 2000 installation for a long time that is linked to several Oracle servers, and it all works very well.

I am trying to migrate to SQL Server 2012 via SQL Server 2008.

I am encountering some problems with the linked Oracle servers on SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2012.

I downloaded the last Oracle 10 Instant Client since we have some older Oracle databases I need access to, and have configured `tns_admin`, and checked with SQL Plus; all good so far.

I created an ODBC system DSN to point to one of the Oracle databases.  I then created my linked server using that DSN.

The linked server returns the standard date query, `select sysdate from dual`, just fine, and will return the count of specific queries too.  However, when I try to return the actual rows from a table, I get a smaller number than I should.

Also, if I run an aggregate GROUP-BY query, I only get one row returned!

I would have tried downloading the full client from Oracle, but in their infinite wisdom, the v10 client is no longer available!

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not use the 11.2 client or ODAC?  They work with a 10g database and work correctly with 2008 R2 and 2012 link servers

Answer (score 1):

The latest full client will work fine with 10g. 
I have experienced similar problems using anything other than the full client, even though according to Oracle the others should work. 
Just make sure that you completely uninstall **all** elements of the previous installs as having multiple clients/versions can create another set of problems.